# How do I pass data to a Fauna Create function

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, faunadb

I am building a Next site and have decided to use Fauna as my database.  On the front-end I am passing an object to my back-end API like so:

```
  async function onSubmit(values) {
    try {
      const data = await postData("/api/put", values);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    async function postData(url = "", data = {}) {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        cache: "no-cache",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        redirect: "follow",
        referrer: "no-referrer",
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });

      return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript object
    }
  }
```

My back-end looks like this:

```
const faunadb = require("faunadb");

// your secret hash
//! -- Replace with secret for prod.
const secret = "Key...";
const q = faunadb.query;
const client = new faunadb.Client({ secret });

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const data = JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2);
  console.log(data);
  return client
    .query(
      q.Create(q.Collection("pages"), {
        data: {
          name: data.name,
          email: data.email,
          title: data.title,
          body: data.body
        }
      })
    )
    .then(ret => console.log(ret))
    .catch(err => console.log("error", err));
};
```

It seems inside the return, `data` is not recognized and the item sent back to the Fauna collection is empty.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

The [Fauna Docs](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/crud_examples) don't show examples with variables.

Comment: What does your `console.log(data)` outputs then? Does it show properly?

Comment: Also, why are you doing a JSON.stringify? Doesn't that make your req.body become a string?

Comment: Before the return, the `console.log(data)` give the data I want.  The JSON.stringify seems to be best practice from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to the following:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.name);
  const bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2);
  // console.log(bodyData);
  return client
    .query(
      q.Create(q.Collection("pages"), {
        data: {
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          title: req.body.title,
          body: req.body.body
        }
      })
    )
    .then(ret => console.log(ret))
    .catch(err => console.log("error", err));
};
```

Works well now!